# Twitter share button opens two tabs on Safari

Tags: twitter, safari, mobile-safari, share, twitter-share

I'm using the following URL to share the page on Twitter:

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=POST_TITLE&POST_URL&via=akhbar`

It works fine with all browsers and mobile devices, except Safari, it opens:

- One tab with the previous URL, but adds the following parameter to the end of the URL: `&original_referer=POST_URL`
- A new window (that shows the Tweet composer) with the original share button's URL.

Why does this happen on Safari? And how to avoid this?

Comment: Is this on Safari on desktop, or mobile Safari?

Comment: Both @AndyPiper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by changing the Twitter share URL to this:

`https://twitter.com/share?url=POST_URL&via=akhbar&text=POST_TITLE`

But I've no idea what are the differences between `intent` and `share`, and why that was happening with the old URL.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the difference but I believe the intent version is current.